# Asp.net windows authentication after restart of website

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

Before restarting my asp.net website both `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` and `User.Identity.Name` correctly contain the user that was authenticated via Windows Authentication.

After restarting my website, `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` shows the application pool name and `User.Identity.Name` contains the text `user-access`.

The user is not required to log back in and seemingly continue to be authenticated, but these fields are now wrong.

This also seem to apply to situations where the keep-alive is turned off, so I assume it is connection related?  It also seems to pop up when multiple people are connecting to the server.

My question is where does this behavior come from? How do I get the username?

Update:
It appears to be either gone, or less pronounced when using the .net 2.0 app pool.

Comment: Can you post code for a controller displaying this behavior? In particular, do you have `[Authorize]` attributes on all of your public actions? In IIS, do you have both anonymous and authenticated access allowed?

Comment: There are no [authorize] attributes, but anonymous access is not allowed, and before shutting it down it does require authorization.

Comment: could you share your authentication and authorization code?